# CSS number format

Tags: css, formatting

I would like to know if it is possible to use CSS to format the visual representation of a number in an input field (text/tel). But not pass the simbols to the back-end.

Ex: (XXX) XXX-XXXX
Where x is any number.

I would like to pass to the db XXXXXXXXXX but have the user see on screen the format so if they type 1231231234, the field will display.

(123) 123-1234

Any ideas just using css?

Comment: CSS can not do that you will need jquery to get this kind of effect..

Comment: @KheemaPandey Let's say javascript, not jquery, OK?

Comment: Why to write a 100 lines of codes when you can achieve goals in just writing a few lines of code.?? check this DEMO. http://jsfiddle.net/hnbx4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span>(</span><input name='area-code' type='number' lenght='3'><span>)<span><input name='first-three'><span>-</span><input name='last-four'>
```

etc see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tqnfbtxj/

Answer (score 0):

Using pure CSS, you can use :before and :after selector in CSS2 or ::before, ::after selector in CSS3
More details are [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp). But it has browser compatibility issues(IE 8.0 and above). And it's not possible to show it across a single text field. So a pure CSS solution will not be sufficient. This is not exactly a limitation of CSS because CSS is meant for the presentation, formatting and display. It's not meant for manipulation. That job is for JavaScript.
One of the solution could be that you use 2 fields. One displayed text field and another hidden field. The displayed text field will take input from user and you can format it using JavaScript code on text change event. The hidden field will be appended with user input without formatting.
This is just one of many ways you can do the formatting.

Comment: Please don't link to W3Schools. They insinuate that they are related to the W3C, but aren't. Instead, use a more canonical source, such as the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before